# sell-out, sell out or sellout?

Tags: grammar

sell-out, sell out or sellout?

I see all three forms on Google Books, but I am wondering if one of them might be incorrect, or if all three forms are accepted by English linguists.

I think only sellout and sell-out should be correct, but I am wondering about the third form.

> He's a sell out," shouted Belial as they sat in his Range Rover
> smoking more weed.

Testimonies of Favor and Compassion - Page 27
Randy Rembert · 2010

Comment: Why do you assume it's just one? Dictionary.com, for example, shows it as both "sellout" and "sell out," which certainly wouldn't rule out "sell-out," especially used as a noun adjunct in a predicate adjective. If you scroll down past "sellout," which provides the meaning you use, you'll see the entry for "sell out," which also provides the same meaning you use: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sellout . My point is, in English, there's often more than one way to skin a cat, so unless you're bound to a style guide that prescribes how you are to write it, it's up to you. Just be consistent.

Comment: You are assuming that all three are variations of each other. They are not, at least not necessarily.